# Modulo of a power set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I am given a modulo of a set A, say 5. I know that the formula for the modulo of the power set is 2^5 however I am not sure why that is the actual formula. (2^n where n is the modulo of the set)

Would anyone be able to explain?

Here's the actual question as I think I'm not fully understanding the question correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR0oJ.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please do not delete posts after having received an answer.

Comment: People commonly [over-]use the vertical line for the following **completely unrelated things**: (1) "$|x|$" is the absolute value of real/complex number $x$. (2) "$||f||$" is the norm of a real/complex function $f$. (3) "$k \mid n$" means "$k$ divides $n$" (i.e. $n$ is an integer multiple of $k$) for reals $k,n$. (4) "$AB || CD$" means "line $AB$ is parallel to line $CD$" for points $A,B,C,D$". (5) $|S|$ is the cardinality of set $S$.

Comment: Don't assume that the same symbol means the same thing. "Mr. Blank" has a dot that is not a full-stop, and the apostrophe in "Janet's cat" and "Janet's a cat" mean totally different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the cardinality of the power set.

For each element in $A$, there are two options, we have to decide whether to include it in a subset or exclude it, hence the formula of $2^n$ by multiplicative principle.